# Percentile rank calculation

Tags: python, statistics, scipy, percentile

I'm attempting to calculate the [percentile rank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile_rank) of a score using the [python statlib](http://code.google.com/p/python-statlib/) module. The *percentileofscore* function is supposed to return a value between 0 and 100, however it regularly produces numbers outside this range. An example:

```
 >> a = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
 >> percentileofscore(a, 0)
 108.33333333333333
```

I've tried the [scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.percentileofscore.html) module, and have also rolled my own with similar results.

Am I misunderstanding something re. this function?

EDIT - More examples:

```
 percentileofscore([23,23,23,25], 23)
 137.5
 percentileofscore([12,19,65,25], 12)
 112.5
 percentileofscore([112,109,605,25], 25)
 112.5
```

Seems that querying the percentile of the lowest score causes the problem. A bug perhaps?

Comment: Interesting indeed. Out of curiousity, could you add some more examples of this?

Comment: A bug without doubt. Nice catch.

Answer (score 8):

[scipy.stats.percentileofscore](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.10.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.percentileofscore.html#scipy-stats-percentileofscore) seems to work as expected:

```
In [2]: import scipy.stats as stats

In [3]: stats.percentileofscore([0,1,2,3,4,5], 0)
Out[3]: 16.666666666666664
```

Comment: I mustn't have checked my imports properly when testing scipy, thanks for clearing that up. Problem appears to be with statlib only.

Comment: I don't think statlib is maintained, while there have been several bugfixes and improvements in scipy.stats in the code that was initially inherited from statlib, for example for this case http://projects.scipy.org/scipy/ticket/560